# QGIS rule-based categorization with multiple variables

Tags: qgis, rendering

There are a few questions which sort of touch on this, but I haven't found an answer that is easy yet.  I have a database with several columns of metadata.  The first column relates to a unique ID I have assigned to point which can be shared among many points.  The second column is the original data source of the point which again can be shared by multiple points.

I would like to plot this data so that the unique ID is categorized by colour and data source is categorized by shape.  This can be accomplished using rule-based categorization, however I have 70,000 data points with 50 sources and 1500 unique ID's; setting up these rules by hand is not feasible for this project.

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure How will you be able to get either 50 different colors or shapes, not to speak of the 1500 unique ids... In this cases I would use lables at least for the unique ids.

Comment: You could write stand alone python scripts for rendering http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/200750/26213.